# Solr ngram does not match the terms with special chars

Tags: solr, autosuggest, n-gram

With the reference to this [blog](http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Advanced-autocomplete-with-Solr-Ngrams-and-Twitters-typeaheadjs.aspx) I added new Solr field type "text_suggest_ngram" to schema.xml as follows.

```xml
<fieldType name="text_suggest_ngram" class="solr.TextField">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" 
                  mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
              generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" 
              catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" 
              catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" 
              maxGramSize="20" minGramSize="1" />
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" 
              pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement="" replace="all" />
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" 
                  mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
              generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" 
              catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" 
              catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" 
              pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement="" replace="all" />
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" 
              pattern="^(.{20})(.*)?" replacement="$1" replace="all" />
   </analyzer>
```

Below is the suggestngram request handler to solrconfig.xml

```xml
<requestHandler name="/suggestngram" class="solr.SearchHandler">
       <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
          <str name="defType">edismax</str>
          <str name="rows">10</str>
          <str name="fl">myterm</str>
          <str name="qf">term_suggest^30 term_suggest_ngram^50.0</str>
          <str name="pf">term_suggest_edge^50.0</str>
          <str name="group.field">term_suggest_ngram</str>
          <str name="sort">count desc, term_suggest_ngram asc</str>
          <str name="group.sort">count desc</str>
       </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

This is working for all cases except if I look for the terms having special char's like "Cars & bikes" or "car.bike" Its ignore special chars & show not relevant results. If I search for rock/roll, it shows rock roll, rockers, rolldown etc.
I tried by putting / before the special character as well.

Comment: I tried with WhitespaceTokenizerFactory tokenizer but it doesn't recognise spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" 
              pattern="([^\w\d\*æøåÆØÅ ])" replacement="" replace="all" />`

This would delete most of the unusual characters. So, that's probably your problem. Try commenting it out and seeing what you get.

But in general, you can look at the analysis screen of the Web Admin UI and see how the text goes through each individual filter and where it becomes what you do not expect. You can even then enter query text on the other side and see if it will match as expected. It's strongly recommended, especially if you just copied the definition without fully understanding in depth what it does.

Comment: Thanks. Alex. Worked. Do you have any idea how should I consider trailing spaces like Alex should results Alex, Alexer, Alexandre but Alex_ where the last char is space should result me Alex but not Alexer, Alexandre. I hope you get me.

Comment: This is a new question, I recommend you post is separately with the simplest example. Either here or on the mailing list.